# export: `)': not a valid identifier

Tags: bash, syntax

I have a simple bash script:

```
# This function cannot be changed
function set_tf_var() {
    variable_name="TF_VAR_$1"
    variable_value="$2"
    echo "Setting $variable_name to $variable_value"
    export $variable_name=$variable_value
}

job_schedule_expression="rate(10 minutes)"
set_tf_var "job_schedule_expression" "$job_schedule_expression"
```

But when I run it, I get the following error:

```
line 5: export: `minutes)': not a valid identifier
```

The following job_schedule_expression's work just fine:

- rate(10minutes)
- rate10 minutes

I don't know how I can escape the parenthesis or something for it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using below line

enclosing variable in double quote may solve your problem.

```
export $variable_name="$variable_value"
```

You need to escape double qutes if your varable contains double quotes using \

Comment: Is there a way to do it without updating the `set_tf_var()` function?

Comment: Backslash, not forward slash, is the escape character. But a string can contain double quotes just fine.

Comment: @Aziz Some workarounds are possible but it quickly gets out of hand. The function definition is buggy; you really need to update it.